# iPhone - Grand Central Dispatch invalid mutable array

Tags: iphone, grand-central-dispatch

if I do this

```
NSMutableArray *allColors;
NSData *dataColor = [dictPLIST objectForKey:@"allColors"];
if (dataColor != nil)   {
    allColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
      [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataColor]];
}
dataColor = nil;
```

my allColors mutable array has valid contents, but if I create a GGC group and do this...

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

__block NSMutableArray *allColors;
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    NSData *dataColor = [dictPLIST objectForKey:@"allColors"];
    if (dataColor != nil)   {
        allColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
              [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataColor]];
    }
    dataColor = nil;    
});

// .... other stuff is added to the group


dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
   dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

    // if I try to access allColors here, the app crashes

   });

});

dispatch_release(group);
```

am I missing something?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an autoreleased array and the autorelease pool is being drained by GCD sometime between when the first block executes and the second block executes.

Any time you are doing concurrent programming, whether by thread or using GCD, you *must always hard retain any object that is to survive beyond one scope of execution*.

Comment: I thought they are automatically retained?

Comment: Not when you add `__block` -- with that storage modifier, the contents of the variable are both writable from anywhere and you are responsible for managing the memory.

Comment: you are right. I had to add __block, or I would not be able to change the contents, but I forgot that doing that, it would not be retained automatically! Thanks!!!